# Stream videos from a server with "youtube-like" compression

Tags: video, streaming, compression, youtube, video-streaming

I would like to host some videos on a site for a small audience (under 50 people), and don't want to use a site like YouTube or Vimeo, however I would like to have the same kind of load speeds for the videos.

In my experience when I put up a 720p video with some h.264 compression there is still some people experience poor loading. Is there a simple solution to provide an option like YouTube has with quality selectors? Obviously I could render multiple versions and upload those, but that seems wasteful.

Is there an optimal way to achieve this?

Currently what I am using is [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) to display the videos which uses Javascript and HTML5 to display and show the video. The video I am showing using videojs is a 720p video rendered with h.264 compression. From YouTube viewing the video in 720p quality is no problem for loading, however from my site there are many times when you must wait for buffering. It has nothing to do with the sites speed, it is plenty fast, however the users are essentially downloading the whole video file, which itself is still a 250mb which is a lot for a user on a slower connection to handle.

Comment: You can do that, but you have to at least tell us what approach to streaming you're using right now. Try to provide as many details as possible.

Comment: Are you against any online service, or just the widely used free ones such as YouTube and Vimeo? (Hint... Wistia is awesome)

Comment: @gronostaj Will add some more details within a few minutes.

Comment: @BrianAdkins I want to self host if possible. I can `scp` over my files to my server faster than I can upload to a site. Along with that many of the people viewing the video are from schools with strict web filters which usually have YouTube/Vimeo blocked. Also for this item I would prefer to have it hosted on my server than someone elses.

Comment: For streaming i would use VLC. If you host your videos the risk is that "load speed" may be limited due to your upload bandwidth. You certainly don't have the same as Youtube ;)

Comment: @user2196728 By streaming however I am not referring to a live stream, I am referring to streaming an already rendered video to an audience much like watching a YouTube video.

Comment: yes i got it. But to me the main point of failure will be your upload bandwidth, which is most of the time lower than download bandwidth on most ISP. While it will take 5s to buffer 2Mb on youtube, it will take 1mn for you...i let you guess what will happen if 10 people want to watch your video at the same time. (my numbers here are just for sample, no calculation done)

Comment: @user2196728 well depends on who is connecting. My internet is only about 5mbps.

Comment: Who is connecting is about their download bandwidth. Who you serve is about your upload bandwidth. `My internet is only about 5mbps` upload or download ? if it's download it should be around 2 or 3 for upload. So nevermind the technology or software you will use, the point of failure is here, you won't do miracles...

Comment: @user2196728 I don't host the server, it is hosted offsite with a much better connection. I am saying that I personally when trying to view the video on my site am even having buffering issues.

Comment: 'Obviously I could render multiple versions and upload those, but that seems wasteful.' -- As I understand it, that is exactly what youtube does. If you want to have multiple video qualities available to your end-users, you have to put multiple videos on your server.

Comment: @evilsoup Okay, so should I be rendering out multiple copies, or is there some script out there that will utilize something like ffmpeg to create internet optimized videos of various sizes?